# How to load test Server Sent Events?

Tags: benchmarking, load-testing, server-sent-events

I have a small app that sends Server Sent Events. I would like to load test my app so I can benchmark the latency from the time a message is pushed to the time the message is received so I can know when/where the performance breaks down. What tools are available to be able to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `Server-Sent Events` it is just HTTP you can use `siege` utility. Here is the example:

```
siege -b -t 1m -c45 http://127.0.0.1:9292/streaming
```

Where:

- **`-b`** benchmark mode i.e. don't wait between connections
- **`-t 1m`** benchmark for 1 minute
- **`-c45`** number of concurrent connections
- **`http://127.0.0.1:9292`** my dev server host and custom port
- **`/streaming`** HTTP-endpoint which respond with `Content-Type: text/event-stream`

Output:

```
Lifting the server siege...      done.

Transactions:                 79 hits
Availability:             100.00 %
Elapsed time:              59.87 secs
Data transferred:           0.01 MB
Response time:             23.43 secs
Transaction rate:           1.32 trans/sec
Throughput:             0.00 MB/sec
Concurrency:               30.91
Successful transactions:          79
Failed transactions:               0
Longest transaction:           30.12
Shortest transaction:          10.04
```

Comment: i'm trying to use siege Server-Sent Events and when i run this command "siege -c2 -d10 -t30s http://streaming_end_point" i get the following, fundamentally everything returns 0 but actually the connections are made successfully, any idea?

Comment: `Lifting the server siege...
Transactions:             0 hits
Availability:          0.00 %
Elapsed time:         29.61 secs
Data transferred:         0.00 MB
Response time:          0.00 secs
Transaction rate:         0.00 trans/sec
Throughput:          0.00 MB/sec
Concurrency:          0.00
Successful transactions:           0
Failed transactions:            0
Longest transaction:         0.00
Shortest transaction:         0.00`

Comment: @Sai that is rather odd, could you please post development server log? Also passing `--verbose` option to `siege` could provide some info.

Comment: thank you for responding, i really appreciate it. I tried running the siege with --verbose but wasn't able to get any information on why it returns everything as 0. I verified the DEV logs and i was able to see the streaming end point being executed the number of times mentioned in the -c value, each request will be associated with a UUID and i was able to see the UUID in the logs but not getting any data back from siege. The siege version i use is SIEGE 4.0.2.

Comment: I have created a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40048289/how-to-loadtest-server-sent-events with little more details about the service and SSE. I was also analyzing the GATLING tool to perform load test for SSE and found a bit info here http://gatling.io/docs/2.2.2/http/sse.html. On the other hand when i use siege against a normal req/res then it works like a charm but for this particular streaming end point it does not return any value.

Answer (score 2):

I took a simple path of creating a shell script that initiates N background jobs of cURL which connected to the SSE endpoint of my service.
To get the exact cURL syntax, open your Chrome web dev tools -> Network tab -> right click on the entry of the request to the SSE endpoint and choose from the context menu "Copy as cURL"

Then you paste that command in a shell script that roughly looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0;
while [ $i -lt 50 ] ;do
    [PASTE YOUR cURL COMMAND HERE] -s -o /dev/null &
    i=`expr $i + 1`;
done
```

This will add 50 background cURL jobs each time it's run. Notice that I added to Chrome's cURL command the params `-s -o /dev/null`. This is to run cURL in silent mode and to suppress any output.

In my case the service was implemented in NodeJs, so I used [`process.hrtime()`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime) for high precision timing to measure the delay of looping through the N connected clients to broadcast the data.

The results were ok: it served 1000+ active connections in ~0.02sec

Keep in mind that if you run server + cURL clients from the same machine, you'll probably hit OS limits of `open files`. To see `open file` limits on your linux box (common case is 1024) run:

```
$ ulimit -n
```

To avoid reaching the 1000+ active cURLs I got, you can:

- start them from multiple machines
- or increase this limit (see sysctl)

The problem I faced was that eventually node crushed with an ELIFECYCLE error and the log was not very helpful in diagnosing the problem. Any suggestions are welcome.