# Server Sent Events Load test

Tags: load-testing, server-sent-events

I have an REST application which sends Server Sent Events (SSE), and would like to performance test it. Are there any tools that I could leverage to performance test it, or any idea how to perform load test if there no tools available?

Comment: You can have 3 machines set up, one for sending post data, one for receiving and broadcasting stream and one for listening the stream.. and compare sent-time with received-time..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load test Server Sent Events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089085/how-to-load-test-server-sent-events)