# How to loadtest server sent events

Tags: javascript, node.js, streaming, load-testing, server-sent-events

I have a node service that streams data via SSE (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sse-channel). I would like to loadtest this service my making 'n' concurrent connections, i tried the "loadtest" npm module but since we are dealing with streaming responses i was not able to report back any data like requests per second, mean latency etc… when the streaming requests are made, is there a way to use "loadtest" module for streaming services if not can someone point me to the module that would report back status while making concurrent streaming requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gatling (http://gatling.io/#/) has support for SSE (http://gatling.io/docs/2.2.2/http/sse.html). It's not in js, it's Scala. But, it's quite simple to write a scenario that targets a SSE server.

Comment: that works, i was able to create a simple scala file to load test the streaming response and was able to get reports back with useful informations. One thing though is with regards to licensing, is it  MIT licensed or is there any restrictions in using this tool?

Comment: Another query i have is, i was able to run the scala file only from gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-2.2.2 folder, is there a way that one can install this tool globally sort of installing a npm package globally by appending -g and then we can use it from any where in the ecosystem.